# Client or Server Script to Print following Form or convert to PDF

Tags: google-app-maker

I am using google app maker and SQL database to build a procedure tracking database.
I this App I have a form which is going to be filled by the user.

[image]

I want the users to have a paper or pdf copy of the form once it is filled for documentation purposes.

I'm facing several issues:

- I have difficulty printing with chrome even after shrinking the form to 595px X 842Px.
- I have used some methods mentioned here but didn't get any success.
- I have tried using a couple of code which uses inner html and window.print. But didn't get any positive results.
- For some reason Chrome does not capture the entire form even after scaling down.

Any ideas on how I can solve those issues?

Comment: Do you need this paper or pdf copy to be available for future use? If so, I would suggest writing your form data to a Google Docs template that then can be converted to a pdf, the pdf file can be in your Google drive and the URL for the pdf could be returned to a link that opens the pdf from where it can be printed.

Comment: You can try css `@page{ size: 150mm 150mm}`

Comment: Hey Markus, I tried the Google Docs method but couldn't the format. And for the size, It got too small, or I am not doing it right.